# typescript compiler options not recognized in visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, npm, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've created an ASP.NET 5 Empty Website project using Visual Studio 2015.
I setup a **tsconfig.json** file with the following:

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
      },
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot"
      ]
}
```

I've setup my **package.json** with the following:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8"

  }
}
```

However, when I make this test page and try and compile I'm told the following:

```
Error   TS1219  Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.  
Error   TS2307  Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. 
Error   TS1148  Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
```

Even though it is configured in my tsconfig.json. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a issue on typescript repository - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3124

Comment: Thanks, that led to the answer. You should post so I can give you credit. I moved my tsconfig.json to the root of the wwwroot site and that fixed it.  Previously it was in the root of the project file. I tried putting it in a scripts folder like suggested in the link but that didn't work. Putting it in wwwroot worked.

Comment: Look at [the documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-TypeScript-With-ASP.NET-5).

Comment: That didn't work, putting it in the scripts folder. Had to put it in wwwroot for it to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

Anuraj led me to the answer, and the documentation as of the time I looked at it said to put it in the /scripts folder but that didn't work either.

Putting the tsconfig.json into the wwwroot folder worked. At least of the time of the versions I was using.